# How to use a method in java to store information from an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For a project that i am doing, i would like to use a separate class to store information of various people in an arraylist. in this case, the method will contain an arraylist of strings to store all my information. when i tried doing this i realized that every time i run the `storage` to add a string to the arraylist, it gets rid of  all previous info from the arraylist.

---

is it possible to make it so both the Strings `Hello, How Are You?` and `I'm fine. How Are You?` add to the array in class `two` without having the array reset once the method is rerun?

```
public class one
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        two t = new two();

        t.storage("Hello, How Are You?");
        t.storage("I'm fine. How Are You?");
    }
}
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class two
{
    public static void storage(String toBeAdded)
    {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        al.add(toBeAdded);
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

Given Output:

`[Hello, How Are You?]
[I'm fine. How Are You?]`

Expected Output:

`[Hello, How Are You?]
[Hello, How Are You?,
 I'm fine. How Are You?]`

Comment: you need to initialize your array list outside your method, but why do you even initialize the object if all you need is static method

Comment: hint: read about java naming conventions. classes go UpperCase. And beyond that: this is really basic stuff; probably explained in *any* book on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to solve your problem:

**Option(1):** Your current **`ArrayList`  scope is local to the `storage` method** because you are creating a brand `new` `ArrayList` on each call (to `storage()` method), but what you need is a `static` `ArrayList` object at class level as shown below, but because you are invoking `storage()` method using an object, this is not preferable option (explained below clearly) and compiler is already throwing a warning and you are ignoring it.

```
public class two {

    private static ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void storage(String toBeAdded)
    {
        al.add(toBeAdded);
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

**Option(2) (Prefer this)**: Remove the `static` scope and declare `ArrayList<String>` as an instance variable as shown below (prefer this option) because you are calling a `static` method using an object reference which is not required and creates confusion.

```
public class two {

        private ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        public void storage(String toBeAdded)
        {
            al.add(toBeAdded);
            System.out.println(al);
        }
    }
```

Always ensure that **`static` variables/methods are invoked using classname (like Two.storage()) without creating any object** because they are class level members i.e., they are not meant for a single object. I strongly suggest you read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and understand this subject more clearly.

---

Apart from above important point, always ensure that you follow the Java **naming standards** like class names should start with uppercase which you are violating.

Comment: Or even better, delete all occurrences of `static` from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring the ArrayList as local variable, use it as a field. Also make the method non-static

```
public class two
{

    private ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void storage(String toBeAdded)
    {

        al.add(toBeAdded);
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your mistake**

Each time you are calling `storage()` method,you are creating a new object of 'ArrayList'.

**Solution**

So,make an object of class `two` and pass it alongwith the string to the method `storage()`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class one
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            two t = new two();

            t.storage(t,"Hello, How Are You?");
            t.storage(t,"I'm fine. How Are You?");
        }
    }

     class two
    {
         ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        public static void storage(two object,String toBeAdded)
        {


            object.al.add(toBeAdded);
            System.out.println(object.al);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your class `two` the problem in the method `storage` your logic isn't right every time you call storage to save new string you create new arraylist `al` which will erase all previous information in the old arraylist.

to solve that define `static` arraylist in class two and add information to it by method storage:

```
public class two
{
  public static ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void storage(String toBeAdded)
    {
        al.add(toBeAdded);
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

**Note** : also `storage` method shouldn't be `static` method because you are creating object of class `two` and calling the method through this object so if you try to test it it will give you warning:

> access static method storage

reason of warning that you are trying to access static method `storage` in your object `t` of class `two`.

when you declare static method in class the right way to call it:

```
ClassName.MethodName()
```

in your example:

```
two.storage("Hello, How Are You?");
two.storage("I'm fine. How Are You?");
```